# Flex box image selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a window with four images inside a responsive flex grid. I would like when clicking an image, this one gets `width=100%` covering (or hiding) the others always inside the flexbox.

I guess is with jQuery and JavaScript but I'm not able to find the way. Any help?

Thanks.

[image: as this image shows]

```css
.wrap {display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;}

.container
{box-shadow: 0.075rem 0 0 0 #C9C9C9,0 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9,0.075rem 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9, 0.075rem 0 0 0 #C9C9C9 inset,0 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9 inset;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
float:left;}

.half
{margin: 0.25rem;}

.photo {width: 15rem;
max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  
<div class="container">
<div class="half">
                    <div id="quarter1">
<a href=""><img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" class="" alt="" title=""></a>
                   
                    </div>    
                    <div id="quarter2">
<a href=""><img class="photo" src="http://yvonnemichaelides.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/clock2.gif" class="" alt="" title="" ></a>
                    </div>                    
</div>
<div class="half">
                    <div id="quarter3">
<a href=""><img class="photo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0387/1545/products/product_analysis_1024x1024.png?v=1426535435" class="" alt="" title="" ></a>
                    </div>    
                   <div id="quarter4">
<a href=""><img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" class="" alt="" title="" ></a>
                    </div>                   
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made few changes to your HTML structure. Run the below snippet

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("photoContainer");
 var containerWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].offsetWidth;

 var myFunction = function(ev) {
  
  if(this.classList.contains('expandImage')) {
  this.classList.remove('expandImage');
  for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
      classname[i].classList.remove('hideImage');
  }

  return;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
      classname[i].classList.add('hideImage');
  }
  this.classList.remove('hideImage');
  this.classList.add('expandImage');
     this.style.width = containerWidth;
  

 };

 for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
     classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
 }
```

```css
.wrap {
 display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
}

.container
{box-shadow: 0.075rem 0 0 0 #C9C9C9,0 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9,0.075rem 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9, 0.075rem 0 0 0 #C9C9C9 inset,0 0.075rem 0 0 #C9C9C9 inset;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
float:left;
position: relative;}

.half
{margin: 0.25rem;}

.photo {width: 15rem;
max-width:100%;
}

.hideImage {
 display: none
}

.expandImage > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  
<div class="container">
<div class="half">
                    <div id="quarter1" class="photoContainer">
<img class="photo" src="http://letsprattle.com/image/prattle-icon-square-white.png" class="" alt="" title="">
                   
                    </div>    
                    <div id="quarter2" class="photoContainer">
<img class="photo" src="http://yvonnemichaelides.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/clock2.gif" class="" alt="" title="" >
                    </div>                    
</div>
<div class="half">
                    <div id="quarter3" class="photoContainer">
<img class="photo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0387/1545/products/product_analysis_1024x1024.png?v=1426535435" class="" alt="" title="" >
                    </div>    
                   <div id="quarter4" class="photoContainer">
<img class="photo" src="http://www.northperthcommunityhospice.org/images/icons/calendar-icon.png" class="" alt="" title="" >
                    </div>                   
</div>
```